# Combine each element of the same line by multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a script that extracts some values from a list of log files.
Each value is inserted in an array.

At the end of the script I'd like to combine each line of each array and export them in an excel file.

Here is the script:

```
 while (1) {
 clear
     $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
     $list2 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
     $list3 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
     $list4 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
     $dir_to_look = "C:\test"
     $30_days_backdate=$(Get-Date).Adddays(-30) ####pour tester
     $contenu = Get-childitem $dir_to_look -recurse LOG20* |where { $_.lastwritetime -gt $30_days_backdate }| Get-Content   
 ############### Fichier log du jour

     foreach ($line in $contenu) {
         if ($line -match "CFTT82E.*IDT=(.+?)\b.*") {

                $str = $line.Split(' ') 
                $props = [ordered]@{    
                 Heure = $str[2] 
                 Date = $str[1]       ############ Heure où le message est apparu ######################
                                   }
        $heure_plantage=$str[2] 
         $date_du_plantage=$str[1]       


             $idt = $matches[1]
                 if(!$list.contains($idt)){
                     if ($line -match "CFTT82E.*PART=(.+?)\b.*") { ############### Récuperrer le nom_du_partner #################
                             $part = $matches[1] 

                                                                 }

                  $list.add($idt)
                  $list2.add($heure_plantage) 
                  $list3.add($part) 
                  $list4.add($date_du_plantage)
                  $conver=$list4 |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$2-$1'} # conversion date en EU 



           }
           }


     }
     ###visual test of the array values
     write-host "$list"
     write-host "$list2"
     write-host "$list3"
     write-host "$conver"

     break }
```

The output of these arrays is this (may contain more values in each line.I left only four values for the purpose of this question):

```
A1512201 A1512204 A1512203 A1512205 
12:20:06 12:20:08 12:20:16 12:20:25 
TOTO      TITI     DPFDDFL PACKA
15-01-14 12-03-14 13-03-14 13-03-14
```

So, I'd like to have the following output in the right order:

```
DATE      HOUR         IDT       PARTNER
15-01-14 12:20:06   A1812201      TOTO
12-03-14 12:20:08   B1212204      TITI
13-03-14 12:20:16   A1912203      DPFDDF
13-03-14 12:20:25   A2012205      PACKA
```

Any suggestion is welcome,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IMHO, you need to re-write this to create custom objects instead of arraylists.  Then you'll have something that's fit to export.

Comment: The while(1) is priceless.

Comment: My problem is solved. I did a lot of modifications on the script and now it works fine.
Thank you

Comment: Your not gonna share your solution with the SO world? PS `Fichier log du jour` sounds delicious

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would give you an example of how to create a custom object, I have always used this for reports and found it very easy and help full.

In the example below I use *Get-WmiObject* to get a list of drive that are physical, I then pass the list to *Select-Object* and then select only the values I want from the out put.

The result is that ***$diskinfo*** is created with a number of objects inside it , each with a DeviceID,FreeSpace and Time property.

By default the WMI out puts the FreeSpace in bytes I wanted it in GB so I created what is called a calculated property. I take the FreeSpace values and divide by 1GB to get it in gigs (this is a well documented trick)

I also wanted the time I ran the report to be displayed but there was no Time property so I created one in this case .

You can see in the example below a simple loop to read out the results.

You could do some thing similar loop thought your logs and add each entry  to a custom object like this and then access it.I have found for me this improved performance in things I did.

**The Code**

```
$diskinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object DeviceID,@{Name="FreeSpace";Expression={$_.FreeSpace/1gb}},@{Name="Time";Expression={Get-Date -format yyyy.M.d.H.mm.ss}}


Foreach ($disk in $diskinfo)
{   Write-Host $disk.DeviceID" "$disk.FreeSpace " "$disk.Time
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share with you my modification,I know that it is not perfect, but it works for me:

> clear
>
> $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
>
> ```
> $dir_to_look = "C:\test"
> $30_days_backdate=$(Get-Date).Adddays(-30) ####pour tester
> Get-childitem $dir_to_look -recurse LOG20* |where { $_.lastwritetime -gt $30_days_backdate }| Get-Content|
> ```
>
> ######### Fichier log du jour ################# <----------------------------------------------A modifier
>
> ```
> ForEach-Object {
> $line = $_.Trim()
>     if ($line -match "CFTT82E.*IDT=(.+?)\b.*") {
>
>
>
>         $idt = $matches[1]
>             if(!$list.contains($idt)){
>                 if ($line -match "CFTT82E.*PART=(.+?)\b.*") { ############### Récuperrer le nom_du_partner #################
>                         $part = $matches[1] 
>
>                                                             }
>
>
>                 $props = [ordered]@{    
>                 Date = $_.Split(' ')[1]|Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$2-$1'}
>                 Heure = $_.Split(' ')[2] 
>                 IDT=$idt
>                 PARTENAIRE=$part      
>                               }
>        New-Object PsObject -Property $props
>              }
>
>
>
>
>       }
>
> }|export-csv .\CFT_ERREURS-$(Get-Date -Format dd-MMMM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss).csv -notypeinformation -Delimiter ";"
> ```